# Assign names to Dataset columns

Tags: dataset, associations

I am constructing a dataset like so:

```
data = Dataset[AssociationThread[Keys[characterCounts], charFrequencies]]
```

which gives me a dataset that looks like this:

[image: dataset]

This is all fine, but as you can see, the columns have no names, so I cannot query the dataset or do any manipulations on the columns because of this. Any suggestions about how to do this?

Comment: Consider https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DatasetWithHeaders

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
data = N @ Normalize[#, Total] & @ Counts @ Characters @ ExampleData[
  {"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}
];

Dataset @ data
```

[image]

```
Dataset[KeyValueMap[<|"char" -> #, "freq" -> #2|> &, data]]
```

[image]

Comment: I always want to know how to get 16 votes. :)

Answer (score 21):

Actully we have a easiest way,suppose you have `dataset` like

```
dataset=Dataset[{{"a", 10}, {"b", 11}, {"c", 12}, {"d", 5}, {"e", 99}}]
```

[image]

You can add a column name

```
dataset[All, <|"char" -> 1, "freq" -> 2|>]
```

[image]

## Performance

But if you have a large data set,I have compared **FIVE** solution here

```
dataset = Dataset[RandomInteger[100, {200000, 2}]];

AbsoluteTiming[dataset[All, <|"col1" -> 1, "col2" -> 2|>];]
AbsoluteTiming[dataset[Map[AssociationThread[{"col1", "col2"} -> #] &]];]
AbsoluteTiming[dataset[All, Apply[<|"col1" -> #, "col2" -> #2|> &]];]
AbsoluteTiming[dataset[All, Association[Thread[{"col1", "col2"} -> #]] &];]
AbsoluteTiming[dataset[All, AssociationThread[{"col1", "col2"} -> {1, 2}]];]
```

> {2.83872, Null}
>
> {0.968482,Null}
>
> {2.15222, Null}
>
> {1.73927, Null}
>
> {3.03586, Null}

Comment: (+1) So you now have half of Kuba’s +16 at least... (while he is on 21 already) :)

Comment: @gwr Anyway, thanks for your that vote. :)

Answer (score 8):

Kuba gave an excellent answer if we can't change the way an original data set is generated. If we can change it, instead of the way it is constructed in the OP, we can do the following:

```
keys = {"a", "b"};
values = {1, 2};
nameKeys = "keys";
nameValues = "values";
data1 = MapThread[<|nameKeys -> #1, nameValues -> #2|> &, {keys, values}] // Dataset
```

Just for fun, if we can't change the original data set in the OP and a transformation is needed, we can use the underlying structure and do the low level manipulation:

```
MapThread[<|nameKeys -> #1, nameValues -> #2|> &, 
          data /. {Association | Rule -> List} // Transpose // Normal] // Dataset
```

Comment: Best answer by far