# Unwanted additional output of a function that manipulates string

Tags: string-manipulation

I would like to write a function which produces a table of the frequencies with which various letters of the alphabet are found in some textual input.

Here is what I did:

```
In[212]:= 
    wordInput = "abcdasdagfkahjbfjasfjas3598713952/35'2.35;'235.f";
    freq[StringInput_] := 
      Tally[Table[
        StringTake[StringInput, {n}], {n, 1, StringLength[StringInput]}]];
    freq[wordInput]

Out[214]= {{"a", 6}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 1}, {"d", 2}, {"s", 3}, {"g", 
   1}, {"f", 4}, {"k", 1}, {"h", 1}, {"j", 3}, {"3", 5}, {"5", 
   5}, {"9", 2}, {"8", 1}, {"7", 1}, {"1", 1}, {"2", 3}, {"/", 
   1}, {"'", 2}, {".", 2}, {";", 
   1}}["abcdasdagfkahjbfjasfjas3598713952/35'2.35;'235.f"]
```

It did create a table of frequencies, but at the end it has this tail

```
["abcdasdagfkahjbfjasfjas3598713952/35'2.35;'235.f"]
```

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lingering defintions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18562/45431). Do `Clear[freq]` and try again.

Comment: related by topic: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136422/5478

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not get the tail. You must have typed something else? This is version 11.1 also you do not need to do

```
 Table[StringTake[StringInput, {n}], {n, 1, StringLength[StringInput]}]
```

to split it. Just use `StringSplit`

```
wordInput = "abcdasdagfkahjbfjasfjas3598713952/35'2.35;'235.f";
freq[stringInput_] := Tally[StringSplit[stringInput, ""]];
Grid[freq[wordInput], Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

`Characters` can also be used as follows, thanks to  Pillsy suggestion in comment below

```
 freq[stringInput_] := Tally[Characters[stringInput]];
```

Comment: `Characters` is more perspicuous than `StringSplit[..., ""]` IMO.